# How to set Double Quotes using VBScript Dictionary in UFT 12.0

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Here I want to Add double quotes (`"`) in my sentence, but it insert Two (") at single place as shown in picture. Have tried `Chr(34)` and `Replace()`.
Please help me to insert double quotes in Dictionary Item using VBScript in UFT12.
I don't want to use Msgbox to display this String.

```
Dim Dict
Set Dict=CreatObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dic("Value")="I went to mall....Where I met my Friends "&Chr(32)&"XYZ" & "DEF"&Chr(34)&". We enjoied a lot."
```

When I "Watched" `Dic("Value")` using UFT12.0 It gives shows :

> "I went to mall....Where I met my Friends ""XYZ & DEF"". We enjoied a
>   lot."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debugger tool displays the value of a string variable as a literal (what you would have to type/paste into your editor). Evidence: the surrounding double quotes.

Your `..  "&Chr(32)&"XYZ" & "DEF"&Chr(34)&".  ..` proves: Using Chr() is inferior (extra function call and noise) and error prone (Chr(wrong number) to escaping " by "".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, in addition to exhaustive [Ekkehard.Horner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28797947/3439404) (returns the string and the position of the first occurrence of `"` and doubled `""` in that string):

```
option explicit
Dim myString0, myString1, myString2, myString4

myString0 = "none double quotes"
myString1 = "with ""double"" quotes 1"
myString2 = "with " & Chr(34) & "double" & Chr(34) & " quotes 2"
myString4 = "twice """"double"""" quotes"

Wscript.Echo Wscript.ScriptName & ": Using Double Quotes" _
  & vbNewLine & myString0 _
  & vbTab & InStr( 1, myString0, Chr(34)        , vbTextCompare) _
  & vbTab & InStr( 1, myString0, Chr(34)&Chr(34), vbTextCompare) _
  & vbNewLine & myString1 _
  & vbTab & InStr( 1, myString1, Chr(34)        , vbTextCompare) _
  & vbTab & InStr( 1, myString2, Chr(34)&Chr(34), vbTextCompare) _
  & vbNewLine & myString2 _
  & vbTab & InStr( 1, myString2, Chr(34)        , vbTextCompare) _
  & vbTab & InStr( 1, myString2, Chr(34)&Chr(34), vbTextCompare) _
  & vbNewLine & myString4 _
  & vbTab & InStr( 1, myString4, Chr(34)        , vbTextCompare) _
  & vbTab & InStr( 1, myString4, Chr(34)&Chr(34), vbTextCompare)
```

**Output**:

```
==>cscript //nologo 28778280.vbs
28778280.vbs: Using Double Quotes
none double quotes      0       0
with "double" quotes 1  6       0
with "double" quotes 2  6       0
twice ""double"" quotes 7       7
```